# How to colour points on QQ plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction... I want to identify different groups on a QQ plot using ggplot... which appears to be easily done in base/stats qqnorm .eg.

```
set.seed(1967)
test <- as.data.frame(cbind( x= rnorm(100,5,2),y=c(rep(1,30),rep(2,70))))

qqnorm(test$x,col=test$y)
```

[image]

but **ggplot** gives me this:

```
ggplot(test, aes(sample=x,col=as.factor(y))) + geom_qq()
```

[image]

How do i achieve the qqnorm plot with ggplot?  I tried searching here... found similar, but no concise answer... surely I'm missing some trivial switch thing?

Comment: I just posted a new answer to the question @Tjebo linked above. Adding an explicit grouping variable (e.g. `aes(group = 1)`) should work for this case too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that we can not color the points via the `color` aes as this splits the data into groups, i.e. we get a qq-plot for each group instead of for the whole sample.

To overcome this problem my approach colors the points via the `color` argument. This however requires some manual work. First. Set up the color vector according to the `test$y`. Second, to get the right colors in the plot we have to order the color vector by `test$x`. Hard work but at least it works. (; Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1967)
test <- as.data.frame(cbind( x = rnorm(100,5,2),y=c(rep(1,30),rep(2,70))))

# Vector of colors
col <- ifelse(test$y == 1, scales::hue_pal()(2)[1], scales::hue_pal()(2)[2])
# Order by x
col <- col[order(test$x)]

ggplot(test) + 
  geom_qq(aes(sample=x), col=col)
```

[image]

PS: Thanks to @Tjebo for checking and pointing out that I don't need `geom_point` to get the right colors.

Comment: @Tjebo. Thanks. You are right. Not sure what I tried. (: Just edited my code accordingly.

Comment: this is just what i needed!   I mashed it all together to into `ggplot(test) + geom_qq(aes(sample=x),col=ifelse(test$y == 1, "red", "black")[order(test$x)])`